# How to reset a javascript timer with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to be able to restart the time interval from within a PHP file.

Here is the JS timer code:

```
var chat_interval = setInterval(function()
{
    $.post("chat_update.php",  function(data) { $("#rect_comments_text").append(data);}  );
}, 4000);
```

What code in PHP will allow me to reset this timer manually?

Comment: Make a callback, which checks, what response PHP returns and based on that, clear the interval.

Comment: Explain your expected behavior in more detail. Can interpret this several ways

Comment: Why you want to clear the Interval? you want that each 4 second the JS will check with the server if there is any updates isn't? (Interval callback repeat itself each X (4000 in your case) milliseconds)

Comment: teresko gave the correct answer, do it like he said.

Comment: I want this to call every 4 seconds, unless called from elsewhere, in which case i want this to reset.

Comment: Unless what is called elsewhere? Not much code context shown to see how this does get called. Please take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: If this chat_update.php file is called from somewhere other than this javascript timer, then I want the timer to reset. How is this ambiguous? It doesnt matter where or why I want to restart the timer, I just need to... I don't want it running more than once every 4 or so seconds, so if its called manually elsewhere, then the timer needs to restart.